# Jquery (select box) remeber previously selected item after back button is issued

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, jquery-easyui

I'm having a jquery easyui combobox with 3 options contained in a `.html` file called for example `test.html`. This is rewriting some `url` in order to pass dynamically its value, when user selects the node it wants to check:

```
<select id="mycombobox" class="easyui-combobox" style="width:90px;" data-options="
 onSelect: function(rec){
  $('a#link1').attr('href', '/scripts/system?' + $('#mycombobox').combobox('getValue'));
  $('a#link2').attr('href', '/scripts/memory?' + $('#mycombobox').combobox('getValue'));
  $('a#link3').attr('href', '/scripts/cpu?' + $('#mycombobox').combobox('getValue'));}">

   <option value="node1">- machine1 -</option>
   <option value="node2">- machine2 -</option>
   <option value="node3">- machine3 -</option>
</select>

 <a id="link1" href="/scripts/system?node1">SYSTEM</a>
 <a id="link2" href="/scripts/olm/memory?node1">CPU</a>
 <a id="link3" href="/scripts/olm/cpu?node1">MEMORY</a>
```

Everything is working just fine, but when the script is ran, and I return to the page where the select is (from where the script was fired, my case `test.html`) the select value returns to initial one `"- machine1 -"`.

What I want to achieve is:
When user selects for instance `"- machine 2 -"` and presses for example `SYSTEM` link, the script is fired, everything runs ok (it is a CGI_BIN which checks some unix stuff and prints in html format where i also insert a back button).

After this when user press 'back button' (back button is a link to `test.html`) I want that when `test.html` page is loaded to have the combobox set with the previously chosen value, in my case: `"- machine2-"`.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Anybody? I searched again on the Google but just couldn't find feature this working at all.

Comment: you try to manipulate it with `cookies`